# Dspace Installation Issue while running ant fresh_install command

Tags: maven, ant, dspace

Previously I worked with the precompiled version of dspace-6_x dspace, It works perfectly, and later I decided to work with the source code directly form a github.

During installation process.

while running `ant fresh_install` command I got an error as shown below.

```
dspace@olenepal:~/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer$ ant fresh_install
Buildfile: /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/build.xml

init_installation:

prepare_configs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
     [copy] Copying 156 files to /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp
     [copy] Copying 16 files to /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp

init_configs:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /dspace/config
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/config-temp

test_database:
     [java] 2017-06-14 10:27:30,904 WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext @ Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl

     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:758)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.SpringServiceManager.startup(SpringServiceManager.java:221)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:212)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:358)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:327)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:906)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:864)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
     [java]     ... 16 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
     [java]     ... 26 more
     [java] Failure during kernel init: Failed to startup the DSpace Service Manager: failure starting up spring service manager: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl

     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:215)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:758)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.SpringServiceManager.startup(SpringServiceManager.java:221)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:212)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:358)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:327)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:906)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:864)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
     [java]     ... 16 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
     [java]     ... 26 more
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure during kernel init: Failed to startup the DSpace Service Manager: failure starting up spring service manager: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:65)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to startup the DSpace Service Manager: failure starting up spring service manager: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:231)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:153)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:49)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failure starting up spring service manager: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:215)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.DSpaceBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dspace-applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService]: : Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:758)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.SpringServiceManager.startup(SpringServiceManager.java:221)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager.startup(DSpaceServiceManager.java:212)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl] for bean with name 'spiderDetectorService' defined in file [/dspace/config/spring/api/core-services.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:358)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:327)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
```

And at the end the error message is

```
BUILD FAILED
    /home/dspace/Documents/pustakalaya-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/build.xml:792: Java returned: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetectorServiceImpl
```

It seems that is not well compilled.
Try to maven again reading all data it return